# Проблемы вывода ANSI в .exe

Tags: python

```
all_flags = []
import  os
import climage as cl
import random
import time  as t
for file in os.listdir('D:\AllFlags'):
    all_flags.append(file.split('.')[0])
def random_flag():
    return random.choice(all_flags)
def game():
    lives = 3
    score = 0
    print('Hello!')
    t.sleep(1)
    print('You quess the flag')
    t.sleep(1)
    print('You have 3 lives')
    t.sleep(1)
    print('Good luck!')
    while lives > 0:
        t.sleep(1)
        flag = random_flag()
        output = cl.convert('D:\AllFlags\\' + flag + '.png')
        print(output)
        t.sleep(1)
        list_of_answers = [flag, random_flag(), random_flag(), random_flag()]
        a = 3
        for i in range(3):
            q = random.randint(0, a)
            print(list_of_answers.pop(q))
            a -= 1
        print(list_of_answers[0])
        t.sleep(1)
        answer = input('What is the flag? ')
        if answer == flag:
            print('Right!')
            score += 1
        else:
            print('Wrong!')
            lives -= 1
            print('You have {} lives'.format(lives))
    print('You lose!')
    print('Your score is {}'.format(score))

while True:
    game()
    print('Do you want to play again? (y/n)')
    answer = input()
    if answer == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        break
```

В пичарме флаги выглядят неплохо, но после конвертации этого кода в exe, бывший флаг это просто набор символов, и это нужно пофиксить

Comment: Консоль Windows не знает ничего про ANSI-последовательности. Можно пофиксить с помощью модуля colorama (нужно импортировать и запустить функцию init оттуда).

Comment: Эм, вы печатаете в консоль PNG-файл?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Библиотека `climage` делает из картинок `ANSI` последовательности. Но в `exe` это не работает у автора

Comment: @insolor, спасибо, но теперь просто черное пространство вместо символов